# Application of Archimedian property

Tags: real-analysis

Given a positive real number a and any natural number $n$, prove that there exists one and only one positive real number $y$ such that $y^n = a$.

I found the solution to this for power 2 i.e. $y^2 = a$ but am not able to extend this to $n$... Please help!

Answer (score 3):

Consider the set $S = \{t \geq 0 : t^n < a\}$. By the Archimedean property of the real numbers, there exists $N \in\mathbb{N}$ such that $N > a$.

Show (using the fact that $f(t) = t^n$ is increasing) that $t < N$ for all $t \in S$. (I can elaborate if you don't see how to do this.)

You now know that $S$ has an upper bound. So it must have a least upper bound. What can you conclude about it?

Comment: @ Dan thanks! ya m able to conclude and write the proof...

Comment: @SheetalSarin: Glad to hear it! `:)`

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Prove, that $$f:\mathbb R_{\geq0}\to\mathbb R_{\geq0},y\mapsto y^n$$
is bijective. Use monotonity for injectivity. For surjectivity, note, that $f$ is continuous, $f(0)=0$ and $f$ is unbounded (Archimedian property), then use the Intermediate value theorem.

Comment: thanks a lot for hint. i m little confused with f is unbounded? for any finite it is bounded and this is used in I.V.T.

Comment: @SheetalSarin: Given an $a$, since $f$ is unbounded, there is certainly some $x$ with $f(x)>a$, also $f(0)=0$, then IVT tells, that there is some $c$ with $f(c)=a$.